# Why fixed div comes out when horizontally scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have demonstrated this problem in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pda2yc6s

On vertical scroll a div becomes sticky. When window is smaller than wrapper width, horizontally scrolling makes sticky to come out of its parent div.

[image]

Here is the css:

```
div#wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1058px;
}
div#mainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 728px;
}
div#sideBar {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
.stick {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 46px;
    width: 728px;
}
```

This javascript makes sticky work:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var s = $("#mainContent h1");
    s.wrap('<div class="sticky-wrapper"></div>');
    var pos = s.position();
    var t = $('.sticky-wrapper');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            t.height(46);
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            t.removeAttr('style');
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }
    });
});
```

Why is this sticky behaving like this? How to solve it?

Comment: ["*...for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport...*"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#fixed-pos)

Comment: just wondering, why not spend your effort on simply making the site more responsive to a narrow screen (rather than trying to make an awkward horizontal scroll to sidebar less ugly)?

Comment: @g13 Is expected result for `.stick` element `width` to be set to 100% of viewport , over sidebar ? , or for sidebar to right to be displayed over `.stick`

Comment: @guest271314 , I expect .stick element to within parent div always

Comment: @g13 Parent `div#mainContent`. appear to have `width` set to `728px` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, it has fixed width of 728px.

Comment: @thedarklord47 I am setting this for media queries greater than 768px. I am working on some responsive design issues.

Comment: @madalinivascu Fixed width comes into play when media queries work for tablet and desktop width. Therefore, using pixels. Otherwise its is reponsive for viewport width less than 768px.

Comment: @g13 still don't really understand. The point of media queries is to avoid having anything like this. If the viewport is big enough, horizontal scrolling is avoided. If it's not, sidebar drops under content (or however you decide to respond) again avoiding horizontal scrolling. I agree with Abhitalks's answer. That will work, but is ugly and you should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first:

1. Per http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#fixed-pos

> ...for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by
>   the viewport...

So, you just can't have an element `fixed` and at the same time keep it confined within its immediate parent.

2. From the same ref:

> For continuous media, fixed boxes do not move when the document is
>   scrolled

Which, means the `fixed` element will not move at all when you scroll. Vertical or horizontal.

---

Now, the problem that you are facing is that you have a page which has a width greater than the viewport and hence triggers horizontal scrolling. Although, your sticky (`fixed`) `div` is of the same width as your main `div`, it will not move when horizontally scrolled and hence will increasingly cover your sidebar, as your content moves left from under it.

If you do not want to restructure your markup to keep everything within the viewport width (*so as not to cause horizontal scrolling*), then you need to manually change the `left` property as you scroll.

You already have an event listener for window scroll. In that add some code to change the `left` property. Like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
    var winleft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        ...
        s.css({'left': -(winleft)});
...
```

**Here is your fiddle with the above incorporated: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pda2yc6s/6/**

What you will be doing is to effectively change the `left` property with the same amount as that of the scrolled horizontal distance. This will keep your `fixed` sticky `div` on top of your main `div` content and not cover the sidebar.

*Note: This is ugly. You may want to rethink your markup and design.*

.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like this:

```
div#sideBar 
{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    z-index:1;
    position: relative;
}

.stick 
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 46px;
    width: 728px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Setting bigger z-index for the sideBar (also with relative postion) makes that the stick element will be overlapped by the sidebar. I suppose that is the effect you want. I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pda2yc6s/2/

Answer (score 0):

Because of position in css:

you are giving position as fixed so that it's behaving like sticky.

change into

```
 .stick {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    height: 46px;
    width: 728px;
}
```

for more about POSITION refer this

http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: You have not understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
div#wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
div#mainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
div#sideBar {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.stick {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 46px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pda2yc6s/4/

Answer (score 0):

It is because the fixed left is calculated from screen left and not document left. So even though sticky header and its parent div have 728px width they don't end at same point.

If horizontal scroll is not a necessity you should make the content to fit in a no horizontal scroll layout otherwise you'll have to recalculate the left position of sticky header on every horizontal scroll change.

Let me know if you need a fiddle

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/dango_x_daikazoku/g589jk0v/1/

```
        var left = $("body").scrollLeft();

        s.css("left", -left + "px");
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight Aman, horizontal scroll comes into play when media queries change for wrapper width greater than 768px (tablet & desktop screens). This makes wrapper width fixed.

Comment: see my edit for a possible solution, but you can also go for a responsive site layout solution like twitter bootstrap to be safer

Answer (score 0):

just change postion value to absolute in ".stick" class in css file like

```
`postion:absolute;`
```

! it works